# $SU(4)$ Structure constants in mathematica

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

How can I write a mathematica function which will output arbitrary structure constants of SU(4)?

Comment: So where did you get stuck?

Comment: You have to demonstrate your attempts to write such a function, otherwise you shouldn't expect any help.

Comment: Mathematica is perhaps not the best software for the task; i think there are better suited programs out there tat has these built-in.

Comment: -1 because you never explain what "SU(4)" means.  It may be due to my own ignorance that I don't know this but you should still not make people dig for information to merely understand your question.

Answer (score 5):

I typically wouldn't respond to an attempt without at least some demonstrated code, but I happen to have a complete answer already coded up for my own purposes.

```
F0 = Sqrt[2/4] IdentityMatrix[4];
F1 = {{0, 1, 0, 0},   {1, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0}  }; 
F2 = {{0, -I, 0, 0},   {I, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0}  };
F3 = {{1, 0, 0, 0},   {0, -1, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0}  };
F4 = {{0, 0, 1, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0},   {1, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0}  };
F5 = {{0, 0, -I, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0},   {I, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0}  }; 
F6 = {{0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 1, 0},   {0, 1, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0}  };
F7 = {{0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, I, 0},   {0, -I, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0}  };
F8 = Sqrt[1/3] {{1, 0, 0, 0},    {0, 1, 0, 0},    {0, 0, -2, 0},    {0, 0, 0, 0}   };
F9 = {{0, 0, 0, 1},   {0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0},   {1, 0, 0, 0} };
F10 = {{0, 0, 0, -I},   {0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0},   {I, 0, 0, 0}  };
F11 = {{0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 1},   {0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 1, 0, 0}  };
F12 = {{0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, I},   {0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, -I, 0, 0}  };
F13 = {{0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 1},   {0, 0, 1, 0}  }; 
F14 = {{0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, I},   {0, 0, -I, 0}  };
F15 = Sqrt[1/6] {{1, 0, 0, 0},    {0, 1, 0, 0},    {0, 0, 1, 0},    {0, 0, 0, -3}   };
F[a_] := {F0, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11, F12, F13, F14, F15}[[a + 1]]
Commutator[A_, B_] := A.B - B.A;
AntiCommutator[A_, B_] := A.B + B.A;

SU4f[a_, b_, c_] := 1/(4 I) Tr[Commutator[F[a], F[b]].F[c]]
SU4d[a_, b_, c_] := 1/4 Tr[AntiCommutator[F[a], F[b]].F[c]]
```

These obey `Tr[F_a F_b]=2 \delta_ab`:

```
Table[Tr[F[a].F[b]], {a, 0, 15}, {b, 0, 15}] // MatrixForm
```

and `[F_a, F_b] = 2 I f_abc F_c`:

```
Fold[And, True, Flatten[
  Table[Commutator[F[a], F[b]] == 
    2 I Sum[SU4f[a, b, c] F[c], {c, 1, 15}], {a, 1, 15}, {b, 1, 15}]
  , 1]
 ]
```

and `{F_a, F_b}=\delta_ab + 2 d_abc F_c`:

```
Fold[And, True, Flatten[
  FullSimplify[
   Table[AntiCommutator[F[a], F[b]] == 
     KroneckerDelta[a, b] IdentityMatrix[4] + 
      2 Sum[SU4d[a, b, c] F[c], {c, 1, 15}], {a, 1, 15}, {b, 1, 15}]]
  , 1]
 ]
```

so that a product may be simply expressed as `F_a F_b =1/2 \delta_ab + (I f_abc + d_abc)F_c`:

```
Fold[And, True, Flatten[
  Table[F[a].F[b] == 
    1/2 KroneckerDelta[a, b] IdentityMatrix[4] + 
     Sum[(I SU4f[a, b, c] + SU4d[a, b, c]) F[c], {c, 1, 15}], {a, 1, 
    15}, {b, 1, 15}]
  , 1]
 ]
```