# Finding trivial solutions, of the type 0 = 0, of an equation involving su(N) structure constants

Tags: matrix, algebra, procedural-programming

so I have a bunch of equations $f_{abc} = f_{egd}m_{ae}m_{bg}m_{cd}$ (sum over repeated indices), where $f_{abc}$ are the structure constants of $su(N)$, for some $N$, and $m_{ab}$ are elements of some matrix. I want to find how many of the $(N^2 -1)\times(N^2 -1)\times(N^2 -1)$ equations above are trivial, meaning that we have 0 at both sides. I did this for $su(3)$ with the code below, and I got the expected answer (I basically used [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56905/su4-structure-constants-in-mathematica) code to build the struture constants). Firts I define `B = 0` as the variable that will do the counting, then

```
For[i = 1, i <= 8, i++, 
For[j = 1, j <= 8, j++,
For[k = 1, k <= 8, k++, 
   If[SU3f[i, j, k] == 0, 
    If[Sum[SU3f[l, r, n]*M[[i, l]]*M[[j, r]]*M[[k, n]], {l, 1, 8}, {r,
         1, 8}, {n, 1, 8}] == 0, B = B + 1]]]]]
```

This gives `B = 176` or something like that in the end. Now, when I do the same thing for $su(4)$ and $su(5)$, only changing the generators and dimensions, I end up with `B = 0`, no equations are trivial, which I find a bit odd. My question is, does my code looks like it does what I want it to do? Is this a good way to do what I described, or is there a better way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost never use `For` since `Table` is preferable.  Never use upper-case letters at the beginning of a variable name (`B`, `M`, `SU3f`) as this may conflict with *Mathematica*'s naming conventions.  I suspect you're a C++ programmer and are quite unaware of the style and syntax of *Mathematica*.

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if you post the _actual_ code you used. At a guess (which is all I can do without the code), I'd try using `Simplify`, `PossibleZeroQ`, or something like that, because sometimes complicated expressions don't get simplified all the way.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes, I'm used to work with C/C++ only, and I'm new to Mathematica. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @aardvark2012 The code is just the one that I posted. The only missing part is the definition of the structure constants that is in the link I also posted. Thanks for the tips.